# Non EU parent to a EU citizen

Tags: visas, schengen, family, latvia, algerian-citizens

I am from Algeria and was married to a woman from Latvia in August 2013 in Algeria. The marriage was registred in April 2014 in a Latvian town hall. We had a daughter in May 2014.

I tried to obtain a short family visa to Latvia 3 times with an invitation in the Hungarian embssay in Algeria (there's no Latvian embassy and the Hungarian embassy represents Latvia). The consul of Hungary refused to give me the visa in the 3 times.

How can I solve my problem and visit my family in Latvia. My dauther is 1.5 years old now.

Comment: Are you still married to a Latvian citizen? What nationality does your daughter have? Did the consul give you a specific reason for the refusal?

Comment: While you want to visit, questions about family reunions *might* be easier to answer on http://expatriates.stackexchange.com. I'm not suggesting this is off-topic here.

Comment: Can you say if you have a criminal record that led to incarceration?

Comment: What reason was given for your refusal?  We cannot solve your problem unless we know what your problem *is.*

Comment: If I understand you correctly, you are trying to join your Latvian wife in Latvia. In this situation, she is not an “EU citizen”, i.e. EU rules do not matter (in most cases) so Latvian law is what matters.

Comment: yes im still married to latvian woman ,my daughter haev double paaport algerian adn latvian, yes they give me reason : your attenion to leave the terrotery of member states before exepiry of them could not be ascertenaid

Comment: me me i never do problem criminal , im clear ,

Comment: me i try join adn viste see my daughter in latvia im from algeria

Comment: adn problem nohvae latvia colsulat in algeria, only latvia country represented by hongry embssay in algers

Comment: and after i try 3 time visa in hongry embssay in algers i try french visa to viste  adn see my wife adn my dautger in french but poroblem french colsulat return my document adn they say not resposbal for visa

Comment: Please edit this additional information in to you question. (also, it's and, not adn)

Comment: Even though I don't know the details of the case, the refusal appears to make some sense. You might very well be tempted to stay and live with your wife (who wouldn't?) so they probably require very solid evidence that you will return to Algeria and/or expect you to apply for a specific spousal visa (not a Schengen visa), which might have extra requirements. Partners of EU citizens have extensive rights but those rules do not cover you because your wife is a citizen of Latvia (they would cover you if your Latvian wife would live elsewhere in the EU than Latvia).